# UIDocumentBrowserViewController allowsPickingMultipleItems is not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have some interesting problem with DocumentBrowserViewController in swift, I want to stop multiple file selection and to hide the Salect button in the navigation bar.

For this reason I use the property allowsPickingMultipleItems but it seams like there is no effect.

I change the property on viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    delegate = self
    allowsDocumentCreation = false
    allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
}
```

I get the code from [here](https://github.com/thesecretlab/Swift-4-Workshop/blob/master/Document/Document/DocumentBrowserViewController.swift)

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: To stop the multiple file selection  and to hide the Select button from the top right corner. This is how it looks now https://imgur.com/a/6eFAq

Comment: refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediapickercontroller/1614671-allowspickingmultipleitems

Comment: @PiyushPatel thans, I saw this and I try it, as you can see in the example I already set the property to false but I still have the multiple file selection and the select button on the top

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug :http://www.openradar.me/33101843
So I change to use the "UIDocumentPickerViewController"

Comment: Please describe your alternative better and write some more details how you worked around this. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

`allowsPickingMultipleItems=false` prevents the user from opening multiple files at the same time (in the doc browser) or picking multiple files at the same time (in the doc picker). This won't ever remove the Select button, which is used to perform actions (e.g. share by email) on items, and which your app cannot control.